# Ordenar como foi digitado (python)

Tags: python

pessoal to com um problema que seria o seguinte, o problema pede pra ordenar os números na ordem que vc digitou eles e depois fazer na ordem inversa, alguem pode me dar uma luz, o codigo é mais ou menos esse:

ps: não é em lista.

esse cont é pq tbm tem q mostrar a media e quantos foram digitados.

(eu to usando o while true, pq no problema ele pra encerrar qnd digitar um número negativo)

```
cont = 0
while True:
    notas = float(input("Informe a nota: "))
    if notas == -1:
        break
    cont += 1
print(cont)
```

Comment: Você pode usar um array?

Comment: Na verdade não, porque não chegamos nessa parte ainda na matéria

Comment: Você não está fazendo nada com `notas`. Não dá pra mostrar as notas se não as armazenar. Não vejo como fazer isso sem uma lista, a não ser criando várias variáveis de antemão, uma pra cada nota (mas daí não se sabe quantas notas vão ser digitadas)

Comment: Eu também estou achando estranho fazer isso sem lista, mas bom, acho que vou fazer com lista

com lista eu acabei de fazer

COM LISTA FICA ASSIM:
cont = soma = media = 0
ordem = []
inversa = []
while True:
    notas = float(input("Informe a nota: "))
    if notas == -1:
        break
    ordem.append(notas)
    inversa.append(notas)
    cont += 1
    soma += notas
    media = soma / cont
print(cont)
print(ordem)
print(inversa[::-1])
print(soma)
print(media)

Answer (score 0):

É realmente algo bem artificial impor um exercício desses e "probir de usar listas" por que "ainda não chegou nessa parte da matéria".

Se por acaso vocês tiveram "como parte da matéria"  a manipulação de textos em strings e os métodos de strings, uma forma de fazer isso é concatenar todos os valores digitados numa string, com um separador, e usar o método "split" para chegar nos valores de volta.

Mas o próprio "for" em Python naturalmente percorre elementos de uma lista - que será o retorno da função "split". 
Eu considero que essa forma de ensinar está *errada*. Se quiser, fique a vontade para colocar esse professor em contato comigo.

```
cont = 0
valores = ""
while True:
    nota_txt = input("Informe a nota: ")
    if float(notas_txt) == -1:
        break
    valores += notas_txt + ","
    cont += 1
for valor in valores[:-1].split(","):
    print(valor)
total = 0
for valor in reversed(valores[:-1].split(",")):
    print(valor)
    total += float(valor)

media = total / valores.count(",")
print("media:", media)
```